# Testing Guzzle 6 Download Progress

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, guzzle, guzzle6

I'm having trouble triggering the 'progress' callback during testing.

Here is the code to be tested:

```
    $this->guzzleClient->request(
        'GET',
        'http://example.com/somefile.csv',
        [
            'sink' => $this->directory . $this->filename . '.csv',
            'progress' => function ($download_size, $downloaded, $upload_size, $uploaded) {
                $this->downloadProgress($download_size, $downloaded, $upload_size, $uploaded);
            },
        ]);
```

I'm able to mock a response and it saves the file, but it never triggers 'progress'. Note: The response options I'm using are the same as the ones I get from the live server.

```
    $mock = new MockHandler([
        new Response(
            '206',
            [
                'content-type' => 'application/octet-stream',
                'Content-Range' => 'bytes 1113-1113/11591523',
            ],
            new Stream(fopen(__DIR__ . '/test_stream_file.txt', 'r'))
        )
    ]);

    $handler = HandlerStack::create($mock);
    $client = new Client(['handler' => $handler()]);
```

I'm considering just testing that the mock file downloads and then testing the `downloadProgress` method separately if that's my only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MockHandler](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Handler/MockHandler.php) does not implement the 'progress' request option.

Testing of the handlers ability to fire the progress callback would be duplication of the Guzzle test suite.  Specifically:

1. [CurlFactoryTest::testEmitsProgress](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/tests/Handler/CurlFactoryTest.php#L259); and
2. [StreamHandlerTest::testEmitsProgressInformation](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/tests/Handler/StreamHandlerTest.php#L349)

If your goal is to test to ensure that the callback performs intended operations, separate that into a different test.

If your goal is to test handler capability, I refer you to the Guzzle Test Suite.

[CurlFactory](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php) is the default handler for non-Windows systems.

[StreamHandler](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Handler/StreamHandler.php) is the default handler for Windows systems.

Comment: Ultimately I settled on just testing the `downloadProgress` method separately. I just would've liked to have tested them together as they are triggered together, but as I was testing the download progress there were several conditions I needed to test so it actually made more sense testing it on it's own.